Read a CSV file with Pandas in Databricks workspace
I've uploaded a notebook on Databricks workspace. The workspace tree looks like this:

I want to read a CSV in the data folder using pandas. I'm trying to do so with the following code in the FastFashionML notebook:
import pandas as pd
items = pd.read_csv('data/fastFasionItemsDim.csv', sep='|')

What I get is:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/fastFasionItemsDim.csv'

This is how the data folder looks like:

Although the extension is not shown in the tree, the file is named fastFasionItemsDim.csv, as I uploaded it using a zip file. I also tried to remove the extension from the file path, but I still can't read the file.
How should I locate and load correctly the CSV file with pandas in the Databricks File System?

It seems that it is not possible to upload csv files using the Databricks FileSystem.
The only way is to upload them through the GUI, and then executing this PySpark and SQL code:
def load_csv_to_spark_df(path, temp_table_name):
    
    # File type
    file_type = "csv"

    # CSV options
    infer_schema = "true"
    first_row_is_header = "true"
    delimiter = "|"

    # Load CSV file into DataFrame
    spark_df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
        .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
        .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
        .option("sep", delimiter) \
        .load(path)

    # Display DataFrame
    display(spark_df)

    # Convert DataFrame to Pandas
    items = spark_df.toPandas()

    return spark_df, items

After loading the table on pandas, if you also want it to be available on the GUI, you should create a view and perform an SQL query:
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/<FILENAME>"
temp_table_name = "<VIEW_NAME>"
spark_df_items, items = load_csv_to_spark_df(file_location, temp_table_name)
spark_df_items.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)

Then, the SQL query:
%sql
select * from `<VIEW_NAME>`

After this procedure, you will have a Pandas dataframe table, and you will also be able to inspect the table graphically in the Catalog section.

you could prefix your path with a / to go to the root directory like this:
import pandas as pd
items = pd.read_csv('/data/fastFasionItemsDim.csv', sep='|')


assuming your python script is FastFashionML.py, it seems that the script isn't launched from the root of your worskpace (which contains the data folder, as well as FastFashionML.py). Can you precise how do you launch your script ?

It is a notebook, i launch it just pressing the play button on the databricks interface

Have you tried closing and restarting your notebook ? Sometimes it doesn't refresh the environment around it.
